# Cannot convert from BSON type to Date MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am trying to filter some data stored in MongoDB using parameters contained in the URL.

My problem is that when the request is sent, the server crashes with the following error:

`can't convert from BSON type string to Date`

I tried changing the type of the variables to `Number` hoping that it would fix the problem but I had the same result.

Here you are the code I use to send the request to the server:

```
async filter(){

        month = this.$refs.month.value;
        year = this.$refs.year.value;

        if(month != "Month" && year != ""){
          const addressToFetch = "/api/budget/" + year + "/" + month;
          console.log("Fetching" + addressToFetch);
          await fetch(addressToFetch).then(response => response.json())
      .then(response => {
          this.expenses = response;
          console.log(response);
      });

        }
    }
```

This function is executed when an HTML form button is clicked and takes values from two form inputs.

Here you are the code I use to handle the request server-side:

```
app.get("/api/budget/:year/:month", verify, async (req, res) => {
  const user = req.session.user;

  const year = Number(req.params.year);
  const month = Number(req.params.month);

  console.log("Got " + year + "/" + month);

  const expenses = db
    .collection("expenses")
    .find({
      "users.username": user.username,
      $expr: {
        $and: [
          { $eq: [{ $year: "$date" }, year] },
          { $eq: [{ $month: "$date" }, month] },
        ],
      },
    })
    .toArray();

  console.log(expenses);
  res.json(expenses);
});
```

I also post the documents stored in the DB for demo purposes:

```
[
    {
        "_id": "6571eb70320499f416931fd8",
        "id": 2,
        "date": "2021-09-06T00:00:00.000Z",
        "description": "boringday",
        "category": "transport",
        "buyer": "giacomo",
        "cost": 49,
        "users": [
            {
                "username": "paolo",
                "amount": 16.333333333333332
            },
            {
                "username": "giacomo",
                "amount": 16.333333333333332
            },
            {
                "username": "giacomo",
                "amount": 16.333333333333332
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "_id": "6571eb70320499f416931fe8",
        "id": 18,
        "date": "2019-04-10T00:00:00.000Z",
        "description": "badday",
        "category": "school",
        "buyer": "giacomo",
        "cost": 329,
        "users": [
            {
                "username": "luca",
                "amount": 109.66666666666667
            },
            {
                "username": "luca",
                "amount": 109.66666666666667
            },
            {
                "username": "giacomo",
                "amount": 109.66666666666667
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "_id": "6571eb70320499f416931feb",
        "id": 21,
        "date": "2021-11-14T00:00:00.000Z",
        "description": "boringexperience",
        "category": "school",
        "buyer": "giacomo",
        "cost": 299,
        "users": [
            {
                "username": "giorgia",
                "amount": 99.66666666666667
            },
            {
                "username": "giacomo",
                "amount": 99.66666666666667
            },
            {
                "username": "giacomo",
                "amount": 99.66666666666667
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "_id": "6571eb70320499f416931fff",
        "id": 41,
        "date": "2020-04-09T00:00:00.000Z",
        "description": "badtool",
        "category": "sport",
        "buyer": "giacomo",
        "cost": 349,
        "users": [
            {
                "username": "franco",
                "amount": 116.33333333333333
            },
            {
                "username": "franco",
                "amount": 116.33333333333333
            },
            {
                "username": "giacomo",
                "amount": 116.33333333333333
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

For example, in the case the form is submitted with values `year=2021, month=11` I just want the third object to be returned.

Can anyone help me solve the problem?

Thank you in advance for your patience!

Comment: also might want to do await db.collection...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your date is in string format saved in the database. You cannot extract the `$year` and `$month` from string directly that's why you are getting the `can't convert from BSON type string to Date`. You either have to save it as `Date` type or convert the string to `Date` type at query time (using `$toDate` operator) before comparing

```js
.find({
  "users.username": user.username,
  $expr: {
    $and: [
      { $eq: [{ $year: { $toDate: "$date" } }, year] },
      { $eq: [{ $month: { $toDate: "$date" } }, month] }
    ]
  }
})
```

[playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Rz-tSG2GKXv)